# fundamental group of SL(n,R)

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-algebras

I want to prove that $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not simply connected. For this, How can I prove that the fundamental group of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=2$ and $\mathbb{Z_2}$ for $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

$SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has the same fundamental group as $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$, which has been computed in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214637/fundamental-group-of-gl-n-mathbbr), using Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gram-Schmidt, $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a deformation retract of $\textrm{SO}(n)$, therefore:
$$\pi_1(\textrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R}),\cdot)\cong\pi_1(\textrm{SO}(n),\cdot).$$
Now, recall that for $n\geqslant 3$, $\textrm{SO}(n)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\textrm{P}^{n-1}$ and that $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ is the universal covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ and it has degree $2$, whence:
$$\pi_1(\textrm{SO}(n),\cdot)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(2).$$

Comment: $SO(n)$ is not homeomorphic to $RP^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you for pointing that out!