# Fundamental group of a component of $GL_n({\bf R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, curvature, fundamental-groups

Let $G$ be a component of $GL_n({\bf R})$ such that element has a positive determenant.

(1) Since it contains $SO(n)$, $\pi_1(SO(n))$ ? What is a fundamental group of $G$ ?

(2) It has a curvature bound ? That is to say, we can have bound $-1$ below or $-\infty$ ?

Comment: The subgroup $SO(n)$ is a deformation retract of $G$ (we have discussed this several times here: if you search a bit you should find it), so $SO(n)$ and $G$ have the same $\pi_1$. On the other hand, for (2) you need to tell us what metric you want to consider, for otherwise we simply cannot answer; being a group, it is natural to consider left invariant metrics on $G$, and then the curvature will be constant, so you question becomes slightly uninteresting!

Comment: ([Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637/fundamental-group-of-gln-c-is-isomorphic-to-z-how-to-learn-to-prove-facts-lik) I wrote the complex case and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214637/fundamental-group-of-gl-n-mathbbr) Quiaochu did the real one)

Comment: $GL_n^+({\bf R})$ can have nonnegative curvature ? Or it is a bundle ? For instance, vector bundle over $SO(n)$ ?

Comment: Milnor mentions a theorem of Wallace to the point that «If the universal covering of G is not homeomorphic to Euclidean space (or equivalently if G contains a compact non-commutative subgroup), then G admits a left invariant metric of strictly positive scalar curvature» in his amazing review *Curvatures of left invariant metrics on lie groups*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ Yes, like $SO(n)$, the group $GL_+(n, \mathbb{R})$ is not simply connected for $n\ge 2$, but rather has a fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for $n>2$.